# Select2 plugin multiple selects only first value from array

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` plugin in my project.

**When I dynamically add values to the `multiple` select as array, it only shows the first value from the array.**

**HTML**

```
<select multiple id="selId" name="selId[]"  required> 
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#selId").select2();
  $("#selId").select2('val', [1, 2]);
})
```

**I want to make select the 1st and 2nd options.**

What I am missing?

**I created a fiddle explains the same [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zfkLbaLt/2/)**

Please give suggestions. Any help could be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
$(function() {
  $("#selId").select2();
  $("#selId").val([1,2]);
  $("#selId").trigger('change');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/otegbdag/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this solution:

```
$(function() {
  $("#selId").val(["1","2"]).select2();
})
```

You can see [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsJoe/zfkLbaLt/3/).